Starting httpd fails in Fedora 39 on WSL2
I installed via WSL2 Fedora version 39, I also installed httpd, but when I run one of this two commands:
systemctl status httpd
service httpd status

I get this error:
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

I need to use systemctl , how can I solve it?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379425/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate tl;dr WSL does not use systemd as init system by default.

Yes, I know, but is there any way to get them to use systemd?

Welcome to the site. If getting WSL to use systemd is your primary requirement, please be sure to edit the question so that this becomes more obvious. Otherwise you will likely attract answers that try to circumvent the problem.

Are you sure that It is WSL2? It seems WSL1.

Yes, i am using wsl2

Edit your Wsl.conf after googling it
